# SQL query to laravel?

Tags: mysql, laravel

I am using `Query builder` in `Laravel` and I want to Translate this `SQL` Query to Laravel Query

> **SQL **

```
SELECT * FROM `directions` WHERE `direction` LIKE "ENERGIE"
```

How do I write This Query in Laravel ? ?

Comment: What have you tried so far

Comment: Have you even tried anything? This is a very simply query...

Comment: Direction::whereLike('direction', 'ENERGIE');

Comment: I have tried this $energie = DB::table('directions')->pluck("direction",'direction');

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on Laravel docs, and assuming you have a directions table in your db, you can do something like;

```
$results = DB::table('directions')->where('direction', 'like', 'ENERGIE')->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have created a model for your Directions table, then it would be like this

```
$results = Direction::where('direction', 'like', 'ENERGIE')->get();
```

If you aren't using wild cards, I don't really see a need for a like statement, it can be simplified to.

```
$results = Direction::where('direction', 'ENERGIE')->get();
```